# @Query Update Command on table is throwing Null pointer Exception

Tags: spring, jpa, nullpointerexception

When I am trying to update a field of table using @Query(value = "Update ",nativeQuery=true) is throwing null pointer exception.

I have tried many approaches which I can find in stack overflow, but no one solves my problem.

**AirCraftRoute.java**

```
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "aircraft_route")
public class AirCraftRoute implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private AirCraftRoutePK pk = new AirCraftRoutePK();

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("airCraftId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "aircraft_id")
    private AirCraft airCraft;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("routeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_id")
    private Route route;

    @Column(name = "journey_date")
    private Date journeyDate;

    @Column(name = "departure_time")
    private Time departureTime;

    @Column(name = "arrival_time")
    private Time arrivalTime;

    @Column(name = "fare")
    private float fare;

    @Column(name = "availability")
    private int availability;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof AirCraftRoute)) return false;
        AirCraftRoute that = (AirCraftRoute) o;
        return Float.compare(that.getFare(), getFare()) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(getAirCraft(), that.getAirCraft()) &&
                Objects.equals(getRoute(), that.getRoute()) &&
                Objects.equals(getJourneyDate(), that.getJourneyDate()) &&
                Objects.equals(getDepartureTime(), that.getDepartureTime()) &&
                Objects.equals(getArrivalTime(), that.getArrivalTime());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getAirCraft(), getRoute(), getJourneyDate(), getDepartureTime(), getArrivalTime(), getFare());
    }
}
```

**BookingService.java**

```
@Service
public class BookingService implements IBookingService {

    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    private AirCraftRouteRepository airCraftRouteRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Booking bookFlight(Booking booking){
//        Long airCraftId = booking.getAirCraftRoute().getId().getAirCraftId().getAircraftId();
//        Long routeId = booking.getAirCraftRoute().getId().getRouteId().getRouteId();
        booking.setBookingReferenceNumber("##YTRJTG");
        booking.setPnrNumber("PNRYTFRYHG");

        int result = airCraftRouteRepository.updateAvailability();
        System.out.println(result);
        //bookingRepository.save(booking);
        return booking;
    }
}
```

**AirCraftRouteRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface AirCraftRouteRepository extends JpaRepository<AirCraftRoute,Integer> {

    //@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE AirCraftRoute ar SET ar.availability = 5 where ar.fare = 2000",nativeQuery = true)
    int updateAvailability();
}
```

**Exception**

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE AirCraftRoute ar SET ar.availability = 5 where ar.fare = 2000",nativeQuery = true)
int updateAvailability();

This is throwing null pointer exception. The error says:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.abc.gds.service.BookingService.bookFlight(BookingService.java:27) ~[main/:na]
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is not missing @Autowired annotation for airCraftRouteRepository?

Answer (score 1):

A good guess would be `BookingService.java:27` is this line

```
int result = airCraftRouteRepository.updateAvailability();
```

Your `airCraftRouteRepository` is null since you didnt `Autowired` it

```
@Autowired
private AirCraftRouteRepository airCraftRouteRepository;
```

Comment: Ops my bad...It works...Very trivial mistake.

I am getting other error now as:-

"Illegal attempt to set lock mode on a native SQL query"

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's better to Update your question or ask another question. Thanks.